# Windows 10 and android nexus 7

Tags: android

I have a Windows 10 desktop and tablet android nexus 7 that are connected via USB cable. But I've only text

```
The folder is empty
```

in desktop nexus7-folder. Can somebody please give well readable and working text?  How to transfer files (images, videos, ..) from tablet to desktop?
Thanks!

Comment: you might be missing android usb driver for your device, windows installs it automatically, but sometimes you have to do manually..

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: Better to ask in https://android.stackexchange.com/ I think